# Removing a key from state causes problems with rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Let's say I'm writing a Todo app that allows to create *groups of todos*.

My state is structured like so:

```
state = {

  groups: {
    groupName: [todoId],
  },

  todos: {
    ids: [todoId],
    byId: {
       todoId: todoObj,
    },
  },
}
```

I'm implementing a `removeGroup` operation. The `groups` reducer would pick all `todoId`s from the given group name, move them to a default group and remove the old group. I'm not mutating the state.

I have three React components, `TodoGroups`, `Group` and `Todo`.

- `TodoGroups` renders a list of `Group`s, based on `groupNames` prop from `getGroupNames(state)` selector.
- `Group` renders a list of `Todo`s, based on `todoIds` prop from `getGroupTodoIds(state, groupName)` selector

The `getGroupNames` just runs `Object.keys(state)` and orders it alphabetically.

---

Now, here is my problem:

When I trigger `removeGroup`, I get a PropType warning that `todoIds` prop is undefined. That warning comes from the `Group` I just removed.

What happens is that `Group` is re-rendered before `TodoGroups` receives new props. Because of that, it still uses the old name and `getGroupTodoIds` returns `undefined` since the old group is not there anymore.

What would be a proper solution to this problem? I could just fall back to an empty array either in `getGroupTodoIds`, `mapStateToProps` or even `Group.defaultProps`, but all of this seems like going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Try adding a div around TodoGroups with a key property that changes when removing a group, for example key={state.todos.ids.length}, this will re-render the entire list instead of only the removed Group

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to help. `TodoGroups` still renders _after_ the invalid `Group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution is probably to not connect the Group component but instead pass down the necessary information from the connected TodoGroups component.

The issue is scheduling: connect will alert all connected components when state changes, but *the existence* of some of these components is itself dependent on state. How does react know not to update the child until the parent completes rendering? You can read more about this and find some other solutions [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/125), though I'm not totally up to date with it.

Also fyi, you're probably not getting anything out of using the `getGroupTodoIds(state, groupName)` selector: selectors are basically just memoized functions that get re-computed every time an argument changes. By calling it with multiple *different* groupName values on every render, it's being re-computed every single time.

Comment: I'm not using memoization in my selector, it's just a handy function that returns a piece of the state.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that the selector terminology is not necessarily tied to reselect/createSelector.